# Make static resource available in Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, asp.net-web-api2

I need to access a web api in an Azure Web Role from a legacy Flash Application, and in order to do this Flash needs to be able to access a file called crossdomain.xml. I have added this file to the root of the application, but if I go to https://myapp.com/crossdomain.xml in the browser the file is downloaded. How can I get the xml to be shown in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static xml files can be served by adding the following to web.config:

```
 <handlers>
    <add name="XMLHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.xml" verb="GET"  />
</handlers>

 <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml" />
 </staticContent>
```